# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

i have one web project that uses wcf web services and it's not works fine.

here i include web config file for more understand :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FolderPath" value="excel/"/>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"/>
  </appSettings>
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      </system.Web>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="99999999"/>

    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="Login.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="infinite">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://staffapi.vayak.net/staff_care_wcf_ws/RestServiceImpl.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb" contract="SC_WCF.IRestServiceImpl" name="" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

when application requests then it's gives me error like this post title

here i include my method to call this services.

```
public void Fill_Combo(Page pg, DropDownList ddl, string combo_type, int Active_Only = 1, int Help_ID = 0, int All_Req = 1, string All_Str = "All", string Filter_Str = "")
        {
            cls_combo obj = new cls_combo();
            cls_combo[] obj_li = null;

            try
            {
                cls_combo_in obj_in = new cls_combo_in();
                obj_in.db_name = CommonLogic.GetSessionValue("sdb_name");
                obj_in.Combo_Type = combo_type;
                obj_in.Active_Only = Active_Only;
                obj_in.help_id = Help_ID;
                obj_in.Add_Str_Req = All_Req;
                obj_in.Add_Str = All_Str;
                obj_in.Staff_ID = Convert.ToInt32(CommonLogic.GetSessionValue("staff_id"));
                obj_in.Is_Admin = Convert.ToBoolean(CommonLogic.GetSessionValue("is_admin")) == true ? 1 : 0;

                obj_li = obj_main.get_combo(obj_in);



                if (obj_li.Length > 0)
                {
                    ddl.DataSource = obj_li;
                    ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
                    ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
                    ddl.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    CommonLogic.SetSessionValue("combo_type", combo_type);
                    pg.Response.Redirect("alert.aspx");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CommonLogic.SendMailOnError(ex);
            }
        }
```

i dont understand what's wrong here please help me up guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are supposed to add **[WebGet]/[WebInvoke]** to the auto-generated operation of the interface so that it maintains consistency of binding between server and client. It located in the auto-generated client proxy class.
We consume the WCF service by adding service reference, there is a difference when the service is created with WebHttpBinding. This type of service is typically called Restful style service, we could call it directly by inputting the service address in the browser.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service
So if we want to consume the service by using a client proxy class, we need to maintain the consistency of binding between the server and client, just like the WCF SOAP service.
Feel free to contact me if the problem still exists.

Comment: how can I contact you??

Comment: ^_^， leave a comment

Comment: can u online and take anydesk if you can prepare??

Comment: Why do you consume the Wcf service created by webhttpbinding by adding service reference instead of inputting the service address in the browser, or creating Soap service with the other binding?

Comment: how can I replace my code as u suggest. I have no much idea about wcf.

Comment: If the server is not on your side, it is a good idea that we send the http request with the Httpclient class in your desktop application. Otherwise we had better consider changing the implementation of the service.

Comment: can u give me some article which describe this give me some links please.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/09/19/wcf-consume-wcf-rest-service-by-httpclient/